# Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey Automatically clicking hidden value with submit value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

There are four hidden values with same input clicks which go like this (below), basically I'm trying to only click a specific one I tried using trigger click jquery but that keeps submitting the first value

```
<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="ball" value="op1">
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Throw!">
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="ball" value="op2">
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Throw!">
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="ball" value="op3">
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Throw!">
</form>

<form action="" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="ball" value="op4">
   <input type="submit" name="action" value="Throw!">
</form>
```

I want to click the third one how can I achieve this with JS/jQuery via using Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey?

This is the current code

```
$("input[value='Throw!']").click();
```

However this always clicks the last one value "op4"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('form').eq(2).find('input[type="submit"]').click();
```

Comment: Problem is there is other forms in the page just not those 4

Comment: In that case, try `$('input[value="Throw!"]').eq(2).click();` or `$('input[value="op3"]').next().click();`.

Comment: No luck with that either

Comment: With the markup you posted, all three of the lines that I suggested will work.  If they are not working for you, then please update your question so as to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, it is difficult to help you. Also, please describe what you mean by "no luck".